# Как исправить ошибку "в запросе нет назначения для данных результата" при вызове созданной процедуры?

Tags: postgresql

Создал процедуру в PostgreSQL при помощи которой хочу легко фильтровать зарплаты в нужных мне диапазонах:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select_salary_range (minSalary INT, maxSalary INT)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $$

BEGIN

SELECT id, first_name, salary FROM person1 WHERE (person1.salary >= minSalary) AND (person1.salary <= maxSalary);
COMMIT;

END;
$$;
```

При вызове созданной процедуры вот таким образом:

```
CALL select_salary_range(5000, 6000);
```

получаю ошибку "**ОШИБКА:  в запросе нет назначения для данных результата**"

В чем моя ошибка? Помогите. Правильно ли создана процедура? В чем ошибка?

Comment: Сервер говорит, что SELECT-то он сделает, а вот куда пихнуть полученный результат - не знает.

Comment: Создайте представление (VIEW), а не процедуру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажеться Вам нужна функция, а не процедура. Pl/pgsql Вам тоже не нужен.

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION select_salary_range (minsalary integer, maxsalary integer)
returns table (id integer, first_name text, salary integer)
language sql as
$$
 select p.id, p.first_name, p.salary 
 from person1 as p
 where p.salary BETWEEN minsalary AND maxsalary;
$$;
-- вызов
SELECT * from select_salary_range(5000, 6000);
```